# strictly increasing function $ f(x) = \frac{{{e}^{bx}}-1}{{{e}^{ax}}-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Show that $f\left( x \right)=\dfrac{{{e}^{bx}}-1}{{{e}^{ax}}-1}$ is a strictly increasing function for $0<a<b$ and $x\ne 0$.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what your problem is.

Comment: $f$ is increasing if $f'>0$. Find $f'$ and simplify.

Comment: Sorry i m new and didn't know the rules.

Comment: i 've found the $f'$ but when tried to show that is $>0$, i encountered an inequality and couldn't show that.

Comment: Which inequality did you encounter?

Comment: how to show $$\dfrac{b{{e}^{bx}}-a{{e}^{ax}}}{b-a}<{{e}^{(a+b)x}}$$ ?

Answer (score 2):

To show that $f(x)$ is increasing, we need to show that the derivative $f'(x)$ (at $x\ne 0$) is positive. We do this for positive $x$ **only**, so the answer below is incomplete.

When we calculate in the usual way, we get that the denominator of $f'(x)$ is positive, and the numerator is $g(x,a,b)$, where
$$g(x,a,b)=(b-a)e^{(a+b)x}-(be^{bx} -ae^{ax}).$$
We have $g(x,a,a)=0$. Let $x$ and $a$ be **fixed**, and let 
$$H(b)=(b-a)e^{(a+b)x}-(be^{bx} -ae^{ax}).$$
Then, differentiating with respect to $b$, we get 
$$H'(b)=(1+bx-ax)e^{(a+b)x}-(1+bx)e^{bx}=e^{bx}((1+bx-ax)e^{ax}-(1+bx))$$
To determine the sign of $H'(b)$, it is enough to find the sign of 
$$(1+bx)(e^{ax}-1)-axe^{ax}.$$
Let $x$ be positive. Then $1+bx\ge 1+ax$, and therefore 
$$(1+bx)(e^{ax}-1)-axe^{ax}\ge e^{ax}-(1+ax)\gt 0.$$

Comment: Why did you choose $\frac{be^{bx}-ae^{ax}}{b-a}\lt e^{(a+b)x}$?

Comment: It comes from work of the OP that I guess I should have repeated. When OP took the derivative of $f(x)$, the condition that the derivative is positive (and therefore $f(x)$ is increasing) turns out to be precisely the condition above. Maybe I should have given the details, but they are familiar to the OP.

Comment: André Nicolas...Thanks for solution.